# Using the auth filter in an api gateway Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I made 2 microservices running on a cluster in Kubernetes , I was able to make an API gateway using spring cloud to call those microservices , and I made a JWT Authorization and Authentication filters in another project .

My question is, how can I integrate these filters in my API gateway to authorize the access to my microservices

```
 spring:
   cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: r1
          uri: http://192.168.49.2:30288/
          predicates:
            - Path= /api1/**

        - id: r2
          uri: http://192.168.49.2:30289/
          predicates:
           - Path= /api2/**
    discovery:
      enabled: false
server:
  port: 8888
```

Comment: Do you have a class like `public class AuthFilter implements GatewayFilter` ?

Comment: hey , thanks for replying , i have two filters , one for the Authentication that extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  and the Authorization extends OncePerRequestFilter , they both manage the access and refresh token, i am new to microservices , and i have no idea how to implement a GatewayFilter using the filters i made , can you please help me

Comment: You can take a look to [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-custom-gateway-filters)